# How to adjust Turbo Boost Ratios on Mac?

Tags: mac, cpu-speed, turbo-boost

My ratios are set to 0035 on my 2012 13" Macbook Air.

In its specs it says that it can be boosted up to 2.8 Ghz. With my current ratios only 2.3Ghz is possible.

Basically I'm wondering how I can change my ratio to something like 006A, or if it's even a good idea.

Comment: Hi Uri, I have unfortunately discovered the same on my 2012 13" Macbook Air just now and posted a question on apple.stackexchange.com. You can read it here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/75747/13414

Comment: This concerns me because Apple *advertises* that this specific Macbook Air should have a Turbo Boost of up to 2.8 GHz as you have noticed already. That's a big difference in single threaded performance! I will call Apple Support in the next few days after Christmas or visit our local Apple Store.